# PowerShell - отправка e-mail

Tags: powershell

Отправляю e-mail средствами **PowerShell**

`Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -To $AdressTo -From $AdressFrom -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Encoding [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

У адресата письмо попадает в папку "Спам" с следующим комментарием

Это письмо попало в папку «Спам» по следующим причинам:
Отправитель не прошел проверку SPF.
Некорректно настроена PTR-запись на домене отправителя.

При отправке письма из браузера письмо не попадает в папку "Спам"

Comment: Полагаю, что для правильного ответа необходимо понимать: корректно ли настроен SMTP-сервер отправляющий почту, корректно ли настроен почтовый сервер принимающий почту, корректно ли функционирует подсистема защиты  SPF, корректно ли указан исходящий почтовый адресанта. Все эти вопросы не имеют отношения к Powershell. Прошу уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос.
Необходимо было авторизоваться.

```
$Msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Msg.From = $AdressFrom
$Msg.To.Add($AdressTo)
$Msg.CC.Add($AdressCC)
$Msg.Subject = $Subject 
$Msg.Body = $Body
$Msg.BodyEncoding = $Encoding
$Msg.HeadersEncoding = $Encoding
$Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, $Port)
$Smtp.EnableSSL = $true 
$Smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($MySecureCreds.username, $MySecureCreds.password)
$Smtp.Send($Msg)
```